# Remove the logo text if its size is 660 pixels

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, viewbox

I have a logo, I want to remove the text of the logo, if the size width is 660 pixels.

Well when I strip out the text with CSS

```
@media (width <= 660px) {
  .LogoMonni-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

svg size remains the same. I want to change the value of the viewBox When removing the text from the logo.is it possible ?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-water-3zphx?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

You should use media query like that:

```
@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .LogoMonni-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use width >= 660px (use min and max)

```
@media (max-width:660px) {
      .LogoMonni-text {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```